# Chrome (Scrolling) and FireFox (Script Crashing)

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, browser

**My System**
Dell Laptop Inspiron 3542, Windows 10 Home, Dell Touch Pad with Driver Version 18.134.40

**My Problem**
Browsers not working properly based on the descriptions below. I don’t care which one to use below, but they have their unique problems. Please help. I did not include MS Edge, which I would use, but it does not have syncing for bookmarks, settings, etc. across all devices.

I have performed much research already on the web, this site and browser boards. However, nothing yet to finally resolve the problems.

**Firefox**

Description of Problem

Firefox constantly freezes with the error message below, which I believe is directly associated with Shockwave Flash:

Firefox gives a "Warning: Unresponsive script" prompt that says "A script on this page may be busy, or it may have stopped responding. You can stop the script now, or you can continue to see if the script will complete."

Attempted Solutions

1. -Ensured latest update of FireFox
2. -Entered “about:support” and selected the “Refresh Firefox…” button
3. -Tools>Addons>Plugins then updated the Plugins
4. -Tools>Addons>Plugins then selected options for the Shockwave Flash plugin and unchecked “Enable Adobe Flash Protected Mode”
5. -Tools>Options>Advanced then unchecked “Use hardware acceleration when available”
6. -Entered “about:config” then double-clicked “dom.max_script_run_time” and changed the value to “20” to allow the
   script to run longer
7. -I don’t have “Webroot Spy Sweeper” which is known to cause this

**Google Chrome**

Description of Problem

In Dell Touch Pad Properties under Gestures>Two Finger Gestures I have selected Reverse Scroll Direction (vertical scrolling), which works well in all other browsers/programs. However, only in Chrome vertical scrolling is backwards compared to all other browsers/progams.

Also, every time I scroll a little square appears then shrinks and disappears quickly. It’s a subtle grey square.

I've learned this problem and solutions exist for mobile browsers (Australian Scrolling fix), but nothing solid for laptop/windows.

Attempted Solutions

1. -Updated Driver for Touch Pad
2. -Uninstalled and installed Chrome
3. -Entered chrome://flags and made all possible adjustments related to scrolling, touch, etc.
4. -Entered settings, but no options for scrolling
5. -Disabled/uninstalled all Chrome extensions

Thank you,
Glenn

Comment: If these are general laptop issues, it's likely the wrong forum to post it. http://superuser.com/

Comment: Sure thing. Thanks, Problem solved on Google Chrome support forum. I had to:
Uninstall current TouchPad driver under “Devices” in Control Panel.
On Dell Driver site at http://www.dell.com/support/home/us/en/19/Drivers/DriversDetails?driverId=G61YTload. Installed Dell Synaptics touch pad driver supported on Alienware Notebook 13 on page

Comment: Good you solved here. Lack of response here is because there are mostly code geeks around...

Comment: Lol, cool. I understand